MS Teams autostarts but setting is off
MS Teams keeps starting on my Windows 11 PC, although the setting is off:

This is my work PC that I'm connected to via Remote Desktop. My home PC also has Teams running. This is annoying, because all notifications pop up twice: in the RDP sesssion and outside
I could not find anything with SysInternals autoruns

A colleague suggested looking at the Windows start apps, and Teams was in that list. I unchecked it, let's hope this kills the issue.
